# Is it possible and advisable to use Antora's UI customization to generate a Google Sheets-like help widget?

Tags: antora

I would like to use Antora to create a Google Sheet-like widget on a web app written in React. I wanted to see if the recommended approach is to write this in React or to utilize Antora's UI customization capabilities.

[image: Google Sheets Help Widget]

I have not tried to prototype either of these approaches yet.

Answer (score 0):

Antora is a static site generator (SSG), so that's overkill for your use case and would add unnecessary complexity.

Antora documentation is authored in Asciidoc. Instead of using Antora, you can use `asciidoctor` to transform Asciidoc->HTML. There is [`asciidoctor.js`](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor.js/latest/), which is transpiled from the `asciidoctor` Ruby source, and that would be a good fit for a React app.